# Spark code takes too much time to run on cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

I have written a Spark application. My code works fine for smaller size population (dataset) but it takes too much time for the larger population (dataset).

Here is the definition of class.

```
case class myClass( d : Int  , max : Double , min : Double  , f:  (List[Double],Double)  =>  Double )   extends Serializable  {
 val random  = new Random()
 var pos      : Array[Double]          =   Array.fill ( d ) (  random.nextDouble()*(max-min)+min  )
 var vel      : Array[Double]          =   Array.fill ( d ) (  math.random)
 var PR     : Double                =   0.1         //Rate
 var LR     : Double                    =   0.95
 var fitness       : Double              =   f (this.pos.toList ,0)
 val Band : Double = 0.001

//Functions definition
def move  (  l_Best : Array  [  Double  ]  ,  sumL : Double , size : Int  ,  f :  (  List  [  Double  ] ,Double  )  =>  Double  )  : (  Array  [  Double  ]  ,  Double   )  = {

 val f   =  math.random   
 val temp1  =  ElementsWiseSubtract  ( pos  , l_Best )
 val temp2  =    temp1.map  (  _  * freq  ) 
 val newVel  =  ElementsWiseSum  ( temp2 , vel  )      // vel == this.vel
 var newPos = ElementsWiseSum  (  pos  ,   newVel )  // pos == this.pos
 if (  math.random   >   this.PR  )  {
    newPos  =  l_Best.map  (  _  *  (  Band *  (  sumL  /  size  )  ) ).toArray
 }
 val nFit = f  (  newPos.toList  , 0  )
 ( newPos   ,  nFit  )
} 
def ElementsWiseSum  (  arr  : Array[Double] , arr1  : Array[Double]   )  :  Array [Double] =  {
 var res  :  Array[ Double ]  =  Array()
 if  (  arr.length  ==  1  )
   res  =  Array  (  arr.head  +  arr1.head  )
 else
   res  =   ElementsWiseSum  (   arr.slice(0, arr.length/2) ,arr1.slice(0, arr1.length/2) )  ++
     ElementsWiseSum  (   arr.slice(arr.length/2,  arr.length ) ,  arr1.slice( arr1.length/2 , arr1.length)  )
 res
}
def ElementsWiseSubtract  (  arr  :Array[Double] , arr1  :Array[Double]   )  :  Array [Double] =  {
 var res  :  Array[ Double ]  =  Array()
 if  (  arr.length  ==  1  )
   res  =  Array  (  arr.head  -  arr1.head  )
 else
   res  =   ElementsWiseSubtract  (   arr.slice(0, arr.length/2) ,arr1.slice(0, arr1.length/2) )  ++
     ElementsWiseSubtract  (   arr.slice  (  arr.length / 2,  arr.length ) ,  arr1.slice  ( arr1.length / 2 , arr1.length )  )
 res
  }
}
```

Main function definition and creation of RDD is:

```
@tailrec 
final def Sphere  (  Alleles:List[Double]  ,  accumulator:Double  )  :  Double =  Alleles match  {
 case  Nil  =>  accumulator
 case  x  ::  xs  =>    Sphere (  xs  ,  accumulator  +  Math.pow  (  x , 2  )  )
}

val N = 10000               // population size
val d =  10000             //  dimensions
val nP = 20               //   partitions
val iterations  = 100000  //   total iterations. This could be less more 
val RDD = sc.parallelize(0 until  N , nP).mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index,iter)  =>
      val data  =  iter.map(i =>
        new myClass(  d, max,min   ,  Sphere   )   )
      data
    }.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)  


val itr = 1 
val res = RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  (index, Iterator) => {
    var li = Iterator.toArray
      li = li.sortWith(_.fitness < _.fitness)

    val res = loop(li, iterations, itr)
    val bests = res.sortWith(_.fitness < _.fitness).take(5).map(x => (x, index))
    bests.toIterator
  }
}
 @tailrec
private def loop(arr: Array[myClass], iteration: Int, itret: Int): Array[myClass] = {
iteration match {
  case 0 => arr
  case _ => {
    arr.map { j =>
      val l_Best = arr.minBy(_.fitness).pos // sort based on fitness
      val l_Sum: Double = arr.map(_.LR).reduce( _ + _ )   // Calculate sum of Rate
      val res = j.move(l_Best, l_Sum, arr.size, Sphere)

      if (math.random < j.LR && res._2 < j.fitness) {
        j.pos = res._1
        j.fitness = res._2
        j.LR = j.LR * 0.95
        j.PR = 0.95 * (1 - math.pow(math.E, (-0.95 * itret)))
      }
    }
    loop(arr, iteration - 1, itret + 1)
  }
 }
}
```

I tested this code on 4 node cluster For **N = 100** and **d = 100**. It takes less than **one minute** to complete **10,000 iterations**, but for **N = 10,000** and **d = 10,000**, it took **19 hours** to complete just **500 iterations**.

According to my observations, functions that do element-wise operations inside **myClass** class taking a long time.
How can I increase its speed? Please give some suggestion. I want to execute it with the following configurations.

N = 10,000 ,d = 10,000 and iterations  = 1000000000 (1 billion )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your element-wise operations, e.g.:

`def ElementsWiseSubtract  (  arr  :Array[Double] , arr1  :Array[Double]   )  :  Array [Double] =  arr.zip(arr1).map(x => x._1 - x._2)`

Comment: We cam simplify but zip is slower than my current method. In zip we have to create extra collection (e.g array)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `.slice()` as well? At any rate I'm getting consistently faster results using my approach on arrays of 1,000,000 elements.

Comment: I made comparison and Zip is faster.\

Comment: I have the same problem as this question. Is it possible to view my problem in this link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669468/why-my-code-takes-so-much-time-to-execute-in-spark-pregel)